# How to reduce MongoDB storage space after deleting a large amount of data

Tags: mongodb, size, database

I have a database in MongoDB, called dump. Currently, it reached 6GB in my server. I decided to delete 90% of data in this database to reduce the disk space it occupied. But after doing that its size is still 6GB, while the true storage size is only 250MB.

I guess this is the design of MongoDB? Is there any convinient way to reduce its size? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size)):

```
$ mongo mydb
> db.repairDatabase()
```

Comment: Sadly, that doens't work with MongoDB 1.8 and journaling enabled.

Answer (score 5):

To compress the data files, you can run either start up MongoDB with `mongod --repair`, or connect to the database through the shell and run `db.repairDatabase()`.

There's also a new [compact](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/compact+Command) command scheduled for v1.9 that will do in-place compaction.

Comment: fyi for 'compact' the docs say: "This operation will not reduce the amount of disk space used on the filesystem. Storage size is the amount of data allocated within the database files, not the size/number of the files on file system." Repair is still the only option to recover disk space.